# Save an image with the same name after editing in python opencv module

Tags: python, image, opencv, save

I'm trying to save an image with the same name after editing on opencv. I can save with the same name. But I can't save in different file. So, this is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob

filename = [img for img in glob.glob("./mypath_1/*.jpg")]
flist=sorted(filename)
images = []
path='./mypath_2/'

for image in flist:
    img= cv2.imread(image)
    alpha=2
    beta=-420

    img2=cv2.addWeighted(img,alpha,np.zeros(img.shape,img.dtype),0,beta)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    cv2.imwrite( path+image, hsv)
```

Additionally, I tried this: `cv2.imwrite( './mypath_2/'+image, hsv)`.

I do not save the image and I do not have a message error in this code.

Some suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #get alpha and beta values
    alpha, beta =2, -420
    # get directory path where the images are stored
    image_dir = "/path/to/image read directory/"
    # get directory path where you want to save the images
    output_dir = "/path/to/image write directory/"
    #iterate through all the files in the image directory
    for _, _, image_names in os.walk(image_dir):
        #iterate through all the files in the image_dir
        for image_name in image_names:
            # check for extension .jpg
            if '.jpg' in image_name:
                # get image read path(path should not contain spaces in them)
                filepath = os.path.join(image_dir, image_name)
                # get image write path
                dstpath = os.path.join(output_dir, image_name)
                print(filepath, dstpath)
                # read the image
                image = cv2.imread(filepath)
                # do your processing
                image2 = cv2.addWeighted(image, alpha,np.zeros_like(image),0,beta)
                hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                # write the image in a different path with the same name
                cv2.imwrite(dstpath, hsv)
                print(image.shape, image2.shape, hsv.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using 3 lines of code using `nipath`

```
import ntpath
filename = ntpath.basename("D:\coding\python\Sample Photos\1.jpg")
cv2.imwrite("D:\coding\python\Sample Photos\"+filename, img)
```